# Inverse airy function of a vector

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I was implementing this function in MATLAB:

[image: function]

with `x` as an input vector `[-0.4:0.1:0.4]` and `alpha` is `12.5` but MATLAB did not have any builtin inverse airy function.

How to implement this inverse of airy function in MATLAB?

Comment: i searched a lot but their is not any formula for inverse of airy function as well as its inverse could not be find out by the formula of airy function. i think it will be implemented in MATLAB by lookup table but dont understand how to built  lookup table of the above equation in MATLAB.

Comment: Given the unique character of the Airy functions (Bessel-like on the negative real line and exponential-like on the positive real line), I'm confident that there is no one-true inverse of the Airy functions since it is not injective (due to the Bessel-like oscillations) and not periodic (unlike sine and cosine). However, an inverse on a near-zero interval may be possible. If so, reposing the equation as a root-finding problem for the inverse at the x-values may allow solution through `fzero` or `fsolve`.

Comment: Problem is their is not any built in command or inverse airy function formula then how i can find out the roots of above function. i have an airy function and  roots of airy function can find easily and i can make a table of it. is their any way to use that table for finding the roots of inverse airy ??